# Automatically detect highs lows of stock prices and draw trend lines in Python

Tags: python, time-series

I am working on a script to find highs and lows of a OHLC data. I am following a long way to find highs and lows and it looks like it kinda works. But does not give me a great solution. Here is the code i wrote so far:

```
df['Highs'] = (df['High'] > df['High'].shift(1)) & (df['High'] > df['High'].shift(2)) & (df['High'] > df['High'].shift(-1)) & (df['High'] > df['High'].shift(-2)), 1, 0)

df['Lows'] = (df['Low'] < df['Low'].shift(1)) & (df['Low'] < df['Low'].shift(2)) & (df['Low'] < df['Low'].shift(-1)) & (df['Low'] < df['Low'].shift(-2)), 1, 0)
```

I am simply following five finger rule. If middle finger is higer than other four fingers it is a high and if middle finger is lower than all other four fingers it is low. This code find highs and lows for me but as i said i am not quite sure if this is the best approach.

So the main reason i am trying to find highs and lows is to draw a trend line virtually and show an alert when the new price crossover a high resistance line or crossunder the support line if any exists at that point.

I really don't need to draw and plot these lines. All i need is to detect the cross over and under.

Let me explain how i would like to use this:

First of all, i will get a time frame. I am working on a 5 minutes historical / intraday data. When I get a new bar's prices, I want to check if the Close price of new bar crossover or crossunder any trend line in the chart. Again it is a virtual line. So all i need is virtually connect highs and lows to eachother. I don't want to plot them. Script will check all high and low points and will detect if it is crossing those lines.

Here is the screenshot to give you the idea.

[image: EURUSD Chart]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We request that you ask a **specific question** about a programming problem you have encountered. As it stands your current question is not specific enough for anyone to give a specific answer. Please take a moment to read [ask] for some tips to improve your question in order to get the information you are looking for.

Comment: This is a specific problem and couldn't find a programatic way. That's why i am asking for help here. But if it is wrong please accept my appoligies

Comment: You have not done anything wrong and don't need to apologize. I want to help, but I don't understand what you are asking for. Please take a few minutes to read the link I gave and then edit your question to improve it.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. I will do my best to be more clear. Reading that link again.

Comment: Also take a look at [help/on-topic] for the guidelines about what is considered "on topic" on this site.

Comment: I have edited my question with my so called English :)

Comment: Okay, that is an improvement. I understand better what you are trying to do. So what is your question? What have you tried to solve the problem? What were your results? Where did you get stuck? And what specifically do you need help with to be able to continue?

Comment: `...i am not quite sure if this is the best approach` - You need to tell us why your solution isn't optimal. How is it deficient?  Is there some example data that could be used to compare/test your solution and other solutions? - [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps I'm a bit late to the party, but [this article](https://raposa.trade/blog/higher-highs-lower-lows-and-calculating-price-trends-in-python/) nicely describes how to detect highs and lows using `scipy.signal.argrelextrema` and how to draw trendlines between consecutive peaks.